# Is it there any advantage to unticking the "Source Code" entry of a repository?

Tags: update-manager, repository

[image: (Source Code)]

Above is a screenshot showing an enabled PPA from the ayatana-scrollbar-team. There are two entries, one with a "(Source Code)" label and one without.

If installing ubuntu on a computer where the user is not very knowledgeable about computers, is there any advantage in unticking the "(Source Code)" entry? For example, will it shorten the time needed for "sudo apt-get update" to complete?

How is the "(Source Code)" repo used? Does it have a purpose on machines used by people who don't even know how to read source code? I'd like to know if I should just keep it enabled or whether I would lose/gain anything by disabling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advantage it exactly what you said, a shorter update time, and the impossibility to download source packages through

```
apt-get source package-name
```

Most users do not download and use source packages anyway. Source packages can be used for code inspection or for recompiling (modifying compilation flags and/or source code)